# Paramiko SFTP connection drops while uploading large file

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I'm trying to upload a large file (1GB) to an SFTP, but I keep getting some variant of:

```
File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/file.py", line 339, in write
    self._write_all(data)
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/file.py", line 456, in _write_all
    count = self._write(data)
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_file.py", line 180, in _write
    t, msg = self.sftp._read_response(req)
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 762, in _read_response
    raise SSHException('Server connection dropped: %s' % str(e))
SSHException: Server connection dropped:
```

I noticed that if I update `MAX_REQUEST_SIZE` (in sftp_file.py) to be 1024 instead of 32768, it works. Does this mean that my only option is to copy/paste a custom version of sftp_file.py with `MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = 1024`? Does anyone else have suggestions that won't slow down uploads?

Update: It ended up throwing a `OperationalError: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected` error the last few times I tried to update the `MAX_REQUEST_SIZE`. For reference, this is what I'm currently doing:

```
    transport = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
    transport.connect(username, password)
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
    f = sftp.open(ftp_path, 'wb')
    f.write(file_obj.read())
    f.close()
    sftp.close()
    transport.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO it's quite strange that you've to reduce the chunksize. SSH's RFC4253 states:

> All implementations MUST be able to process packets with an
>      uncompressed payload length of 32768 bytes or less and a total packet
>      size of 35000 bytes or less (including 'packet_length',
>      'padding_length', 'payload', 'random padding', and 'mac').

Anyway what you can do instead of using a custom version of `sftp_file.py` is something like:

```
sftpclient = sshclient.open_sftp()
with sftpclient.file(remote_file_path, mode='w') as rem_file:
    rem_file.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = 1024
    rem_file.write(data)
```

And play around with `MAX_REQUEST_SIZE` (i.e. 16384, 24576, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I've added open/close before using the get and for some reason that I don't know, it works with big files.

```
    file = self._connection.open(remote_path, 'rb')
    file.close()
    self._connection.get(remote_path, local_path,callback=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am receiving the error- "ERROR_SFTP_PULL, AUTHENTICATION ERROR Server connection dropped":
-Normal passwordless sftp (get) is working to the remote server from my local server, however SFTP PULL is failing through Python script. It was running normal 4 days ago.
-It looks bad at below code part:

```
1.  authReturnCode = "<class 'paramiko.ssh_exception.BadAuthenticationType'>", not sure please help
2. **errorKey = "INFO_SFTP_PULL, "+ eachFiles + " successfully copyied from SFX for " + custName**

Failure log:
===========
2021-04-26 15:00:02,459 INFO::ipndProxyApp.py:787: Processing data for: eDCP
2021-04-26 15:00:02,851 INFO::transport.py:1746: Connected (version 2.0, client SSHD)
2021-04-26 15:00:03,860 INFO::transport.py:1746: Authentication (publickey) successful!
2021-04-26 15:00:03,922 INFO::sftp.py:158: [chan 0] Opened sftp connection (server version 3)
2021-04-26 15:15:15,376 INFO::sftp.py:158: [chan 0] sftp session closed.
2021-04-26 15:15:15,491 ERROR::ipndProxyApp.py:119: ERROR_SFTP_PULL, AUTHENTICATION ERROR Server connection dropped:

Normal log is:
=============
2021-04-22 15:00:02,138 INFO::ipndProxyApp.py:782: Processing data for: eDCP
2021-04-22 15:00:02,256 INFO::transport.py:1746: Connected (version 2.0, client SSHD)
2021-04-22 15:00:02,563 INFO::transport.py:1746: Authentication (publickey) successful!
2021-04-22 15:00:02,586 INFO::sftp.py:158: [chan 0] Opened sftp connection (server version 3)
2021-04-22 15:00:09,999 INFO::sftp.py:158: [chan 0] sftp session closed.
2021-04-22 15:00:10,003 INFO::ipndProxyApp.py:122: INFO_SFTP_PULL, FILE_2021-04-21-18-00-35.txt successfully copied from SFX for eDCP

Python Code:
===========
import os, sys, logging, shutil
import pysftp, mysql.connector
import subprocess, csv, argparse
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

# Importing Configuration settings or other supporting scripts
import settings
import SQLqueries
import fieldLengthVerification

# Static Configuration settings, logging settings, global variables
logging.basicConfig(filename='/var/log/ipnd.log', format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s::%(filename)s:%(lineno)d: %(message)s', dateformat='%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S',level=logging.INFO)
currentDateTime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
currentDate = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
yesterdays_date = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
twoDaysBack = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=2)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None


# Handling Authentication errors for the SFT authentications only
def errorHandling(errorFromProgram):
    """
    Function to handle authentication error for sftp only, it accepts exception errors and return string keyword.

    Parameters:
    errorFromProgram (class) : Error class generated by Exceptions

    Returns:
    str: str(errorFromProgram) or "Authentication Success" or "AUTHENTICATION ERROR " + str(errorFromProgram)
    """

    # This function to perform error handling and return string against the provided input  
    
    authReturnCode = "<class 'paramiko.ssh_exception.BadAuthenticationType'>"

    # Handling RHEL version of sftp (<class 'paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException'>)
    if str(errorFromProgram) == "Authentication failed.":
        errorKeyWord = str(errorFromProgram)
        return errorKeyWord

    # Handling SUSE version of sftp (<class 'paramiko.ssh_exception.BadAuthenticationType'>)
    elif str(type(errorFromProgram)) == authReturnCode:
        errorExcetption,a = errorFromProgram
        errorKeyWord = errorExcetption
        return errorKeyWord

    # Handling other situation then provious two
    elif (str(errorFromProgram) != "Authentication failed.") or (str(type(errorFromProgram)) != authReturnCode):    
        errorKeyWord = "AUTHENTICATION ERROR " + str(errorFromProgram)  
        return errorKeyWord

    # Handling other conditions if not handled in provious if and elif
    else:
                infoKeyWord = "Authentication Success"
        return infoKeyWord


# Fetch eDCP Data files from SFX sftp server

def fetchFilesFromSftpLocation(custName, fileSrcHost, remoteFileLocation, fileSrcUser, fileSrcPassPhrase, dateToProcessFiles):
    """
    Function to fetch files from remove servers and store in location directory, return nothing and accept following parameters

    Parameters:
    custName (str): Customer Name.
    fileSrcHost (str): Hostname (FQDN) or IP address of the source server from where files would be fetched.
    fileLocation (str): Remote file location.
    fileSrcUser (str): User to connect remote server to fetch files.
    fileSrcPassPhrase (str): Password to connect remote server to fetch files.
    dateToProcessFiles (str): Date to fetch the files for   
    """

    # try to connect SFX server over sftp
    try:
        sftp = pysftp.Connection(fileSrcHost, username = fileSrcUser)

        # change to remote directory
        sftp.chdir(remoteFileLocation)
        listOfFilesAtSFX = sftp.listdir()

        for eachFiles in listOfFilesAtSFX:
            
            if eachFiles.startswith("IPNDUP" + custName.upper() +"_" + dateToProcessFiles):
                
                # Fetch files from SFTP
                try:    
                    sftp.get(eachFiles)
                                        
                    **errorKey = "INFO_SFTP_PULL, "+ eachFiles + " successfully copyied from SFX for " + custName**

                except Exception as e:
                    errorKey = "ERROR_SFTP_PULL, "+ errorHandling(e)
                    #print(errorKey)

        sftp.close()

    # Capture Exception
    except Exception as e:
        errorKey = errorHandling(e)
        errorKey = "ERROR_SFTP_PULL, "+ errorKey


        # Checking conditions to generate ERROR or INFO
        if len(errorKey) > 0:
                listOfErrorKeys = errorKey.split('_')
                if "ERROR" in listOfErrorKeys:
                        logging.error("%s" % errorKey)
                        sys.exit(1)
                else:
                        logging.info("%s" % errorKey)

        else:
                logging.error("%s" % "No Error keywords found")
```